# Where can I find a the code related to custom block in Wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I am now looking into a legacy Wordpress project with some custom plugin that are written by previous developer that no longer work in the company. I am a PHP developer but haven't touched Wordpress for some time. I have done some research on Google and it seems that to add a new block type in a plugin, it is the `register_block_type()` function. I found in the plugin code that there is a few `register_block_type()` in one of the files, but not all custom block are found. To be specific, the custom block circled in the screenshot (the one named "Cards") are all not found anywhere in the plugin code.

[image]

I am sure it is added in the plugin, as all the custom block types are gone when the plugin is disabled, but where else in the plugin / what other functions can the custom block types be added?

Comment: There is no single place this is done. It could be done purely in JS (which is generally not advised, but possible), and likely findable in a PHP file.
It's going to be either in plugins or themes. Search your folders for `register_block_type` - on linux you could do something in the likes of `grep -R "register_block_type" /var/www/my_wordpress_folder/*`

That will get you closer, to where you should look. Or you could also search for cards, but that is likely even more generic.

Comment: @Frizzant
I have searched for "Cards", but this name is too generic and there are too many hits everywhere. I have searched `register_block_type()`, as mentioned in the question, so I guess it is possible to be added by JS. May I have a bit more information on how to add it by JS?